# How do I reduce notoriety in the woods?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reduce notoriety in the frontier?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95132/how-to-reduce-notoriety-in-the-frontier)

I got bored and attacked some redcoat convoys in the woods, and now I'm fairly notorious. I have two little icons of notoriety now (in an area where, as [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95132/how-to-reduce-notoriety-in-the-frontier) notes, the general base notoriety is one symbol). Is there a way to reduce this notoriety without going to a different area (or heading back to Boston to take down some signs)?

(I don't believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95132/how-to-reduce-notoriety-in-the-frontier), though the answer may be the same. This is about notoriety that I earned through my actions in the frontier, not the base notoriety that you automatically have in certain frontier areas. Additionally, the answers ended up being different: it seems that I encountered a bug.)

Comment: Does going to Boston or New York to lower it even work? Your wording suggests so.

Comment: @Jeff, unclear so far.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I disagree that this is a duplicate of that question - since that one was in essence "why do I have notoriety I didn't earn or deserve in the frontier?" and mine is about reducing notoriety I earned myself through my actions. The answer is also different - it seems I may have encountered a bug.

Comment: The answer states "**You can't** - you always have some base notoriety in a lot of places in the frontier." So, in the end it answer your question, No?

Comment: @Michel nope - the answer that worked was moving between areas to clear the bug and reset the meter to whatever the base was supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have extra notoriety in the frontier, it is site specific (like when you attack a fort), mission specific (a few missions take place in the frontier and they have a special notoriety conditions) or a bug. During normal game play, it is impossible to raise your notoriety in the frontier. I have managed to bring notoriety into the frontier, but if it didn't disappear immediately, it did either when I crossed a border or fought the first patrol. This leads me to believe that the frontier is coded to enforce level one inside it's boundaries.

Comment: I haven't verified your answer, but I'm accepting perhaps prematurely because it looks like my question might get closed :)

Comment: why would this question get closed?

Comment: and I did all the use cases I thought of killing all the guards, killing some of the guards and running, keeping the active combat timer running for twenty plus minutes, leading one group of guards into another while the combat timer was active and none of them raised my level.

Comment: Yup, seems like I ran into a bug. Crossing a border cleared it somehow.